# Open link in iframe and scroll to the iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, hyperlink

I managed to get a link to open in an iframe.  But since that frame is at the bottom of the page, I want to scroll there at the same time in one click.
How?

Link

```
<a href="ccs.html" target="result-view"><button id="click" class="btn
btn-table">View Details</button>     </a>
```

iframe with resize to content

```
<iframe name="result-view" width="100%" scrolling="no" onload="resizeIframe(this)"></iframe>


      <script>  function resizeIframe(obj) {
obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';  } </script>
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve. and show your html code for that

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post EFFORT and CODE.

Comment: I marked as duplicate - you tagged bootstrap so I assume you have jQuery. Let me know if it should be closed as a different duplicate